# What is the difference between the various syscalls in MIPS for random numbers?

Tags: mips

What is the difference between the various syscalls in MIPS for random numbers? Specifically, I'm looking at 41 vs 42 and 43 vs 44. Also is there any guideline as to what seed I should use or is that completely arbitrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are described in the [documentation](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html):

- syscall 41 generates a random (32-bit) integer.
- syscall 42 generates a random (32-bit) integer in the interval `[0, $a1[`.
- syscall 43 generates a random single-precision float in the interval `[0, 1[`.
- syscall 44 generates a random double-precision float in the interval `[0, 1[`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the documentation for me. I read that like 20 times and didn't understand what it was saying.